# How can I take a value calculated in a if statement and use it outside the if statement?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement

I would like to know how I can take a calculated value from an if statement and use that value for something else. This is just a portion of my code, the portion that I need help with:

```
    double taxedIncome;
    double reducedTax;
    int reductionFactor1 = numberSchool;
    int reductionFactor2 = numberChildren - numberSchool;

    if (income == 10000 && housingCosts > 8000 || income < 10000) {
        taxedIncome = income * 0.18;
    }

    if (housingCosts < 6000 && numberChildren >= 2 && numberSchool >= 1) {
        reducedTax = taxedIncome - ((1000 * reductionFactor1) + (500 * reductionFactor2));
        System.out.println(reducedTax);
    }
```

As you can see in the first if statement, it says that if income (which is a user entered value) is equal to 10000  and the housing costs (also user entered) is greater than 8000 or if income is less than 10000, then income will be multiplied by 0.18.

```
taxedIncome = income * 0.18;
```

However, when I try using the calculated value which is taxed income from the first if statement in the second if statement `reducedTax = taxedIncome - ((1000 * reductionFactor1) + (500 * reductionFactor2));` , it gives me the error:

> variable taxedIncome might have not been initialized

So my question is, how can I take that calculated value from the first if statement and use it in the second one?

Comment: Hint: what happens when the code doesn't enter the `if`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see what you mean now. I should make an else statement if the user entered values do not meet the conditions of the if statement. So what I have done is make `taxedIncome = income` in an else statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this:

- Calculate and save before the if, reuse in the if.
- Calculate in a method that can also be called by the if
- Use the fact that assignment returns a value

However, the problem you're encountering is specifically that not all paths initialize `taxedIncome` before it is used.

You're telling the computer that if a certain case is true then `taxedIncome = income * 0.18;` It's asking, "ok, so what should it be if it's not?"

If that answer isn't exactly the same consider adding an else to your first if.  If you'd put a default value here consider setting `taxedIncome` to the default value at the start.

Comment: I have just changed it so that it is now `if (income == 10000 && housingCosts > 8000 || income < 10000) {
            taxedIncome = income * 0.18;
        } else {
            taxedIncome = income;
        }` and it has fixed the problem. Do you think that's the right way to do it?

Comment: That works.  But sounds very much like a default value.  Consider setting it to that at the start and you're code will be open to the addition of other special cases.

Comment: So you think I should set `double taxedIncome = income;` at the beginning?

Comment: It leaves your code open to the addition of more cases.  Default values should never be buried in an if structure.  Say them loud and proud right at the start.

Comment: Alright, thanks for the help, it is working now. If I come across any more problems, I'll be sure to update this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's good practice to initialize your variables as you declare them.  Typically, you'd want to initialize numbers to zero.

In your case, it's possible that your if statement may not execute so taxedIncome may never have been assigned a value

```
    double taxedIncome = 0; // Initialize to zero or some default value
    double reducedTax = 0; // Initialize to zero or some default value
    int reductionFactor1 = numberSchool;
    int reductionFactor2 = numberChildren - numberSchool;

    if (income == 10000 && housingCosts > 8000 || income < 10000) {
        taxedIncome = income * 0.18;
    } else {
        // If you initialized taxedIncome to zero you may want to default it to some other value if you if statement results in false.
        // taxedIncome = ???
    }

    if (housingCosts < 6000 && numberChildren >= 2 && numberSchool >= 1) {
        reducedTax = taxedIncome - ((1000 * reductionFactor1) + (500 * reductionFactor2));
        System.out.println(reducedTax);
    }
```

Comment: I have added an else statement just like you have where I said `taxedIncome = income` so now it is `if (income == 10000 && housingCosts > 8000 || income < 10000) {
            taxedIncome = income * 0.18;
        } else {
            taxedIncome = income;
        }` Do you think that's the right way to do it?